# Best Practices: Whats the best approaches to handle the unexpected errors between writing into Firestore and Uploading to Cloud Storage

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am developing a phone application using Firebase cloud services. The App is publishing new activities with images and captions.

The way I'm thinking is writing activity first into Firestore and then use the Firestore's generated id to name the image in Cloud Storage.

But, The question is. What's the best approach to handle errors if the app was able to write into the Firestore BUT not able in Storage? How is the whole thing will impact the user experience?

Not Sure, If saving the image into the phone filesystem temporary until getting it uploaded the right wat? OR Prompt the user about the failing process? But again this will costly by deleting the activity from Firestore or how to manage it if the user already lost the connectivity for some reason.

There are a lot of items it could happen during this process with a lot of possibilities. What do you think?

Thanks,

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/ei8tu9/best_practices_whatre_the_best_approaches_to/

Comment: Its off-topic for Stack Overflow, I'm deleting this post and keep reddit. Thanks

Comment: You got an answer here, and not on Reddit. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is a very open ended question as the answer is *what do YOU want do to in those cases*? You know there was an error, so how do YOU want to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

There is really no "best practice" here, other than writing the code that meets the needs of your app.

If an operation fails for whatever reason, and you need to revert other operations due to that fail, you will simply have to write code that undoes what you did previously.  So, if you created a document in Firestore, then uploaded an image in Cloud Storage, but the upload failed, you will have to decide what you want to do with that document.  Maybe you want to delete it, or maybe leave it around to use later. It's up to you - we can't tell you what your app ought to do, but you can write the code that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Doug, for sharing your thought, I totally agree with you about writing the code, but I am still looking for and hear more opinions about the best behavior let's say within the application to avoid the high cost and increase performance.

Comment: Asking for opinions is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If you want to discuss ideas and opinions, please post to a discussion group, such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: Will do that, Thank you